# Facing issue while deploying maven project over liferay server

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6

While deployment of maven liferay project on server I am getting this error:

> 08:56:46,766 INFO [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][BaseDeploer:975] Not updating nok.win.loc.gw.form.portlet because version 6.2.3 is newer than version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: its clearly telling something related to version mismatch

Comment: but it was working fine previously :-/

Answer (score 1):

Check the version in your `WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.xml`, `WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties` or `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. It seems that it is set to `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` now, but it was set to `6.2.3` before.

I would guess that you have deleted the first two files (`liferay-plugin-package`), thats why it is read from `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` now - which in a Maven Build usually contains the POM version.

Comment: performed right click > nok.win.loc.gw.form.portlet > maven > Update Project